# Can we execute N1QL query in exetrnal UDFs in couchbase?

Tags: javascript, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

How we can execute N1QL query in External UDF ?

I am using couchbase 7.0 beta version

I am trying to figure out Can we execute N1QL query in exetrnal UDFs in couchbase? ...... If we can then how?

External UDF support javascript only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Developer Preview available today, it's not possible to run N1QL inside JavaScript UDFs. However, we're actively working on this, and it should be available to preview soon. Basically, our goal is to make all the language features available in [Couchbase Eventing](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-examples.html) in N1QL JavaScript UDFs. Stay tuned for more updates in the coming month or two!